# C: sscanf assignment suppression and the return value

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to use sscanf in C to get some values from a string. However, if the string has more values than I want, I need it to throw an error. ie. if I want an integer, "2" should be ok, but "2 5" should crash.

Now using the return value on sscanf like so:

```
if (sscanf(mystring, "%d %*s", &num) == 1)
```

doesn't work because it'll return 1 even if the string is longer. I CAN do this:

```
char tmpString [100];
if (sscanf(mystring, "%d %s", &num, tmpString) == 1)
```

which works fine, but it's not particularly nice. Is there another way? Can I use the assignment suppression and still get the return value I want?

edit
This is the code I've used:

```
char c; // This is a global variable, just gets used over and over.
sscanf(mystring, "%d%c", &num, &c);
    if (c == '\n') {
```

Comment: I usually do:  `char c; if (sscanf(mystring, "%d%c", &num, &char) == 1)`

Comment: Well if you just want it to crash, you can use:
`sscanf(mystring, "%d %d", &num1, &num2);` (=

Comment: Thanks Jared. Same code as mine I guess but more efficient using only the one char. Works great.

Comment: In your particular case, you could use `strtol` and check that the end pointer is `\0` afterward.

Comment: Regarding your chosen solution, I'd be cautious of reusing `c` because if it reads a `'\n'` once, but the next invocation fails to read anything, it will not necessarily be clear that it has failed as it will still have the value `'\n'`. Using a local variable and initialising it to 0 would not have a noticeable performance impact, and would avoid that problem entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is:

```
int pos;
if (sscanf(mystring, "%d %n", &num, &pos) == 1)
{
    if (mystring[pos] != '\0')
        ...oops...extra data...
    else
        ...only number...
}
else
    ...not even one number...
```

The `%n` is part of C89.  It is not a particularly commonly used (or widely known) conversion specification.  It does not get counted as a conversion (hence the test for `1`).

Comment: Thanks. This seems much more complex than Words Like Jared's code above: `char c; if (sscanf(mystring, "%d%c", &num, &char) == 1)`. Is there any benefit?

Comment: Your choice; it isn't all that complex, and doesn't complain when there's just blanks (white space) after the number, whereas Word Like Jared's code will give you an error if there's even a space or newline after the number.  Of course, it depends on what you want.  The `%n` also allows you to start scanning after the end of the number if that's what you want (probably not in this context).

Comment: Ok thanks. I've used a mix of your code and Jared's as I need it to throw an error if there are blank spaces after the number, but not if there are newlines. I've put the code at the end of my OP.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler test, using just the `scanf` return value instead of one test of the return value and one of the character count, is possible with:

```
if (1 == sscanf(mystring, "%d %c", &num, &(char){0}))
```

This works because, if there is any character after the trailing spaces are consumed, a second assignment is performed, so the return value is 2 instead of 1.

(The `(char){0}` is a compound literal that provides a temporary object to hold the assigned `char`, after which it is discarded.)